# Make all elemants of a character vector the same length

Tags: r, string

Consider a character vector

```
test <- c('ab12','cd3','ef','gh03')
```

I need all elements of `test` to contain 4 characters (`nchar(test[i])==4`). If the actual length of the element is less than 4, the remaining places should be filled with zeroes. So, the result should look like this

```
> 'ab12','cd30','ef00','gh03'
```

---

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570860/adding-na-to-make-all-list-elements-equal-length). Yet, I need to work with a character vector.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `base R` functions to pad 0 at the end of a string to get the number of characters equal.  The `format` with `width` specified as `max` of `nchar` (number of characters) of the `vector` gives an output with trailing space at the end (as `format` by default `justify` it to `right`.  Then, we can replace each space with '0' using `gsub`.  The pattern in the `gsub` is a single space (`\\s`) and the replacement is `0`.

```
gsub("\\s", "0", format(test, width=max(nchar(test))))
#[1] "ab12" "cd30" "ef00" "gh03"
```

---

Or if we are using a package solution, then `str_pad` does this more easily as it also have the argument to specify the `pad`.

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(test, max(nchar(test)), side="right", pad="0")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please explain the `"\\s"` part?

Comment: @llya It means a single space.  You can read more about from `?regex`