# Convert a list of dataframes of different lengths to an array

Tags: arrays, r, list, dataframe

I currently have a list of 7 dataframes, each of which have 24 columns, but not the same number of rows. I would like to convert my list to a 3-dimension array, but I can't because all the components of my list do not have the same dimension. I have 
one dataframe with 60 rows, 4 dataframes with 59 rows, and 2 with 58 rows.

When I try `laply(mylist, unlist)`, I get the following message: Error: Results must have the same dimensions.

Is there any way to put those dataframes into an array? How could I get to put NAs at the end of the 6 other dataframes in order to get them to 60 rows?

Comment: This should get you most of the way there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570860/adding-na-to-make-all-list-elements-equal-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about real purpose of OP which lead him to think of creating a `3-D` array, for which he needs all data frames of list containing same number of of rows.

But, whatever the reason be, one can achieve it using `lapply`. Please make a note that `lengths` function doesn't work properly on list containing data frames. As `lengths` function simply returns number of columns in each data frame contained in list.

Hence, the approach is to first find maximum number of rows in a data frame contained in `mylist`. And then iterate over each data frame to extend its rows to maximum number of rows.

```
# Find maximum row across all data frames in mylist
maxrow <- max(sapply(mylist, nrow))

# Iterate over and increase the row count to maxrow
mylist_mod <- lapply(mylist, function(x,nRow){
                if(nrow(x) <  nRow){
                  x[(nrow(x)+1):nRow,] <- NA
                }
                x
              }, nRow = maxrow)

mylist_mod
# $df1
#   one two three
# 1 101 111   131
# 2 102 112   132
# 3 103 113   133
# 4  NA  NA    NA
# 5  NA  NA    NA
# 
# $df2
#   one two three
# 1 201 211   231
# 2 202 212   232
# 3  NA  NA    NA
# 4  NA  NA    NA
# 5  NA  NA    NA
# 
# $df3
#   one two three
# 1 301 311   331
# 2 302 312   332
# 3 303 313   333
# 4 304 314   334
# 5 305 315   335
```

**Sample Data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(one = 101:103, two = 111:113, three = 131:133)
df2 <- data.frame(one = 201:202, two = 211:212, three = 231:232)
df3 <- data.frame(one = 301:305, two = 311:315, three = 331:335)

mylist <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)

mylist 
# $df1
#   one two three
# 1 101 111   131
# 2 102 112   132
# 3 103 113   133
# 
# $df2
#   one two three
# 1 201 211   231
# 2 202 212   232
# 
# $df3
#   one two three
# 1 301 311   331
# 2 302 312   332
# 3 303 313   333
# 4 304 314   334
# 5 305 315   335
```