# Multiple String splits in R, after a particular character value

Tags: r

I have a dadtaframe with a genre column with data like this :

**genre:**

```
[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
[{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
[{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
```

I need something this way, the word after the string **"'name':"**:

```
genre1    |   genre2   |  genre3 
Animation |   Comedy   |  Family 
Adventure |   Fantasy  |  Family 
Comedy    |   Drama    |  Romance
```

I tried str_split_fixed option,  but the result isn't as expected. Any direction would help.

Comment: May be you need to use `jsonlite` package

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Comment: Please provide your data in an easy to reproduce form.

Comment: This appears to be incorrect [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/), namely it is using single-quotes instead of double. This can be compensated for. Is the data in a file or in a vector?

Comment: Its in vector format. Its in a dataframe and genre is a column in the dataframe. jsonlite didnt work , it threw the error as you conveyed @r2evans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be incorrect [ndjson](http://ndjson.org), since it is using single-quotes. But this is otherwise usable, so we can parse it as JSON (with a fix); trying to parse JSON with regular expressions will likely give pain and frustration and regret.

Data:

```
vec <- c("[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]",
"[{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]",
"[{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]",
"[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]")
```

### Brute-force with Regular Expressions

I'm not even going to attempt it: [Regex for parsing single key: values out of JSON in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8750127/3358272). Other Q/As exist for other languages that all say the same thing: do not attempt. You can contrive a regex that handles "perfect" and "identically-structured" json, but as soon as valid-but-different json structuring comes along, you're done.

Avoid this.

(Using any string-split function is effectively attempting vanilla/fixed regular expression work. I'm not trying to start a flame-war over the semantics of `str_split_fixed`, `strsplit`, ... versus complex regex operations, I think the end-result is that there are great json-parsers out there, and they are much better/faster/more-robust than any string-splitter we can concoct.)

### Brute-force with `jsonlite::fromJSON`

The first cut at code just processes the vector as-is. It's a little inefficient in that it is calling `fromJSON` independent for each one. If your vector is short then this might not be a problem. If this is taking a while, you might want to proceed to the use of `stream_in`. (Note that this is *not* treating it like ndjson.)

```
ret <- lapply(gsub("'",'"',vec), jsonlite::fromJSON)
str(ret)
# List of 4
#  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ id  : int [1:3] 16 35 10751
#   ..$ name: chr [1:3] "Animation" "Comedy" "Family"
#  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ id  : int [1:3] 12 14 10751
#   ..$ name: chr [1:3] "Adventure" "Fantasy" "Family"
#  $ :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ id  : int [1:2] 10749 35
#   ..$ name: chr [1:2] "Romance" "Comedy"
#  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ id  : int [1:3] 35 18 10749
#   ..$ name: chr [1:3] "Comedy" "Drama" "Romance"
```

To extract just the names, this works:

```
lapply(ret, `[[`, "name")
# [[1]]
# [1] "Animation" "Comedy"    "Family"   
# [[2]]
# [1] "Adventure" "Fantasy"   "Family"   
# [[3]]
# [1] "Romance" "Comedy" 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Comedy"  "Drama"   "Romance"
```

Note that your columnar output format won't work with the sample you gave me without extending each vector to be the same length (if so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570893/3358272).

```
ret2 <- lapply(ret, `[[`, "name")
ret2 <- lapply(ret2, `length<-`, max(lengths(ret2)))
do.call(rbind, ret2)
#      [,1]        [,2]      [,3]     
# [1,] "Animation" "Comedy"  "Family" 
# [2,] "Adventure" "Fantasy" "Family" 
# [3,] "Romance"   "Comedy"  NA       
# [4,] "Comedy"    "Drama"   "Romance"
```

(This is a `matrix`, you can take it to the next level.)

### Slightly faster with `jsonlite::stream_in`

(This is treating your data like NDJSON. It's a nuance, not critical.)

If you need to speed this up a little, you can use `jsonlite::stream_in` either on the original raw file (preferred) or, if you don't have it in a raw file, then we'll `textConnection`ize things are fake it (slightly less efficient than a raw file, but should still be faster than `jsonlite::fromJSON`).

```
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(paste(gsub("'",'"',vec), collapse="\n")))
#  Imported 4 records. Simplifying...
# Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2
```

I kept this error here to demonstrate that `jsonlite`'s default is to try to convert simple lists into frames. It doesn't always work, and in this case it is trying to `rbind` them, and the third element (with one fewer element) is causing some problem. We can mitigate this by turning off frame-ification.

```
str(
  ret <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(paste(gsub("'",'"',vec), collapse="\n")),
                             simplifyDataFrame=FALSE)
)
#  Imported 4 records. Simplifying...
# List of 4
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 16
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Animation"
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 35
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Comedy"
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 10751
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Family"
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 12
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Adventure"
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 14
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Fantasy"
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 10751
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Family"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 10749
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Romance"
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 35
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Comedy"
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 35
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Comedy"
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 18
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Drama"
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ id  : int 10749
#   .. ..$ name: chr "Romance"
```

This is a little different than the first attempt, but not at all hard to extract.

```
lapply(ret, sapply, `[[`, "name")
# [[1]]
# [1] "Animation" "Comedy"    "Family"   
# [[2]]
# [1] "Adventure" "Fantasy"   "Family"   
# [[3]]
# [1] "Romance" "Comedy" 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Comedy"  "Drama"   "Romance"
```

(Using the same steps to column-ize things as above.)

This call may seem odd in that it is a double-`*apply` call. It is equivalent to (but shorter than):

```
lapply(ret, function(x) sapply(x, `[[`, "name"))
```

Comment: Thanks much. This solution worked. I am making progress in my use case!