# Get names of table columns within a named list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a named list with tables (1 or 2 columns).

```
mlst=list(test1 = table(c(rep("x", 12), rep("t", 10))), 
          test2 = table(c(rep("y", 20), rep("z", 5))), 
          test3 = table(c(rep("w", 30), rep("m", 50))))
 

$test1

 t  x 
10 12 

$test2

 y  z 
20  5 

$test3

 m  w 
50 30 


do.call(rbind, mlst)
       t  x
test1 10 12
test2 20  5
test3 50 30
```

As you can see, the columns names are t and x, but each title is different.

Here you see it's easy to get the names of the list.

```
names(mlst)
[1] "test1" "test2" "test3"
```

But how can I get the names of the columns of the tables in a new column?

```
      v1 v2 v1t v2t
test1 10 12   t   x
test2 20  5   y   z
test3 50 30   m   w
```

Same as above but a data frame has 1 column, the other 2.

```
  mlst2=list(test1 = table(c(rep("x", 20), rep("t", 10))),
             test2 = table(c(rep("z", 30))),
             test3 = table(c(rep("w", 40), rep("m", 60))))
  do.call(rbind, mlst2)
       t  x
test1 10 20
test2 30 30
test3 60 40
```

But you see that this last command prints non-sense for test2 (recycling the z var, in this case it should be `test2 30 NA z NA`)

I'm trying to avoid for loops for efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
cbind(do.call(rbind, mlst), as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(mlst, names))))
       t  x V1 V2
test1 10 12  t  x
test2 20  5  y  z
test3 50 30  m  w
```

Comment: Excellent! So `do.call(rbind, mlst)` finds the 'numerical values' (frequencies) and `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(mlst, names)))` finds the names of each of those values. What about uneven data like `mlst2`?  `t  x V1 V2 test1 10 20  t  x test2 30 30  z  z test3 60 40  m  w`

Comment: @M.Beausoleil you would need to add extra columns to those members of `mlst2` that are less than `max(lengths(mlst2))`. You could do this inside an `lapply` call.

Comment: Something like this?:   `list.table.to.df  = function(data) {cbind(do.call(rbind, data), as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(  lapply(data, `length<-`, max(lengths(data))),names))))    }` This still recycle the z vector, but the second entry for z is empty... halfway through what I need!

Comment: I used this trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570860/add-nas-to-make-all-list-elements-equal-length

Comment: I could clean it with `df.tmp = cbind(do.call(rbind[...];  names(df.tmp) <- c("fq1","fq2", "v1", "v2");  df.tmp[df.tmp$v2 %in% "",c("fq2","v2")] = NA`

Answer (score 1):

An approach without a loop construct, exploiting `as_tibble` to get the right data structure and row names

```
library(tibble)

setNames(data.frame(t(as_tibble(mlst)), 
         t(data.frame(mlst)[,seq_along(mlst) + (seq_along(mlst) - 1)])), 
  c("v1", "v2", "v1t", "v2t"))
      v1 v2 v1t v2t
test1 10 12   t   x
test2 20  5   y   z
test3 50 30   m   w
```

In case of `mlst2` with non matching list lengths using `sapply` (needs to be 2 separate calls to get numbers as numeric)

```
setNames(data.frame(
  t(sapply(mlst2, \(x) 
    c(x, rep(NA, max(lengths(mlst2)) - length(x))))), 
  t(sapply(mlst2, \(x) 
    c(names(x), rep(NA, max(lengths(mlst2)) - length(x)))))), 
  c("v1", "v2", "v1t", "v2t"))
      v1 v2 v1t  v2t
test1 10 20   t    x
test2 30 NA   z <NA>
test3 60 40   m    w
```